# Privacy protected RPC Channels

Tags: rpc, privacy, dpapi

As the title says, i'm wondering what these are. I know about RPC but what do the prefixed adjectives mean?

P.S.: I came across this term while reading about DPAPI @ MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms995355.aspx#windataprotection-dpapi_topic04 (in bullet point number 6)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but maybe they refer to this: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-nfsv4-rpcsec-gssv3-04